# Should add redundant column or should follow 3NF? How to design a relationship to both parent and child table and still enforce the intergrity?

Tags: database, relationship, parent-child

I am designing a database for a competition. I have several tables like these

```
competition(cid (PK), competition_name), 
participant(pid (PK), participant_name), 
category(catid (PK), category_name, cid (FK) ), WHERE cid REFERENCES competition(cid)
```

Now the participant will participate to a competition and will be assigned a badge to access to the competition's facility and the badge is treated as participant's ID. It is declared in like so

```
part_comp( 
   badge (PK), 
   pid, 
   cid,
   UNIQUE(pid, cid),
   UNIQUE (badge, cid) 
)
```

Participants may compete on 1 or more categories. This relations can be presented in table

```
part_category(
   badge,
   catid,
   PRIMARY KEY (badge, catid)  -- a participant can participate a category ONCE
   FOREIGN KEY (badge) REFERENCES part_comp(badge),
   FOREIGN KEY (catid) REFERENCES category(catid),
)
```

This design meets 3NF, but it is hard to enforce the value of `catid` to make sure it belongs to the competition that is associated with value of `badge` .

**My question is** : should I add a redundant column, let says "cid" to part_category table to make it easy to enforce integrity on catid field like following:

```
   part_category(
     badge PK,
     cid,  <-- this is redundant column 
     catid,
     -- to make sure this category belong to the participated competition
     FOREIGN KEY (cid, catid) REFERENCES category(cid, catid),

     -- to make sure the badge is the one associated with the competition cid
     FOREIGN KEY (badge, cid) REFERENCES part_comp(badge, cid)

   )
```

Or leave the part_category table to meet 3NF, then use either logic in application or write a complex trigger to make sure the column `catid` belong to the competition that associate with `badge`?

The problem become more complex when competitions has sub categories and participants are allowed to compete at some sub-categories instead of the whole 1 category. Which way should I go?

Comment: `(badge, cid)` should be a foreign key which points to another table which records the relationships between badges and their associated competitions.

Comment: Yes, I will add that